# Door sign for Halloween in the corona crisis

Tags: fonts, critique, typesetting

I am not a professional designer. I used a tool called canva to create a door sign for this Halloween. I just want a good looking door sign because people in my household sadly are part of the risk group, so we can't do trick and treat this year.

I wanted to make it black and white because of my printer. This is what I have produced:

[image]

I think it is ugly. Any recommendations on how to improve it? I don't want figures, images or colour into it. Just black and white. But I think the fonts are poorly chosen and the text is misplaced.

Fonts used:

1. Poiret (font sizes: 200, 120, 200)
2. Gagalin (font size: 300)

Comment: I think it's fine. It's for one night on your door. No need to overthink things. I simply turn the porch light off and don't answer the door. A sign isn't really necessary, at least here.

Comment: I doubt anyone will really care, but coronavirus is one word, not two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mind it as much.  A very common design look is to make every line the same width, which is accomplished either by font sizing, letter spacing, compressing the letters, etc.

I don't mind the two different fonts, it adds to the contrast, but I would make the NO HALLOWEEN bigger to fill the box more, and break the third line into 2 lines, and maybe make the fonts the same size.

Maybe something like this:

[image: No Halloween]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it really is ugly :)

But if you're not a designer and this is just for friends & family, then it doesn't really matter what it looks like.

Still, to give some direction I would just use the Gagalin font for everything, and just make the 'No Halloween' part larger. Possibly much larger than the rest, think 1:2 aspect ratio. Center everything on the page and scale it up to fit the entire page. Black fonts, no backgrounds.

You don't need 2 fonts for this, you don't need 4 different font sizes, and definitely don't need a black box in the middle.

Comment: See, I would disagree about the black box, I think it adds contrast `:)`

Comment: Ok, maybe keep the box. Let's go with that :)

Comment: Just my 2 cents.

Do not give more information than needed. 

You do not need to tell people that you are on a risk group. They could imply you are above some age, you are ill or something that can give some "burglar type" person some ideas.

Give responsibility to them:

"We all need to reduce the risk of spreading the covid"

"Thank you for your thoughtfulness"

---

I am thinking of a "humoristic" text.

"There is a monster lurking out there, more scarry than a ghost"

"No Halloween this year"